# Bootstrap: Facebook-like chat message navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

(I deleted my other post as I wished to update with what I have so far)

I wish to make a navigation bar for chat history, much like Facebook does. I want my users grouped vertically with their profiles images and last message sent displayed neatly, like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcZaZ.png

However, this layout is problematic for the following reasons:

1. (Fixed) The list does not seem responsive in the way that I want it to be (hovering over individual users merely highlights the hyperlink)
2. There is no spacing between the image and the person's name/last message sent (how can I fix this?)
3. The search bar at the top is not pulled along with the entire bar-width (I tried using pull-right, but this does not seem to do the trick)
4. The entire bar is locked to the left side. Ideally, I want there to be some margins, similar to Facebook's style. What can I use to get this?

I used the Dashboard layout (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/) as a starting point.

Here is what I have so far with bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/ico/favicon.ico">

<title>Chat</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style type="text/css"></style><style id="holderjs-style" type="text/css"></style></head>

<body style="">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar">
      <li class="clearfix"> 
 <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </li>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">

        <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
          <img src="http://www.goldenmeancalipers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/mirror11.jpg" class="img-circle" height="40" width="40"/>
        </span>
          <div class="chat-body clearfix">
              <div class="header">
                <strong class="primary-font">User A</strong> <small class="pull-right text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>10 mins ago</small>
              </div>
              <p> 
                Last message sent A
              </p>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>


        <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
          <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01079/health-graphics-20_1079972a.jpg" class="img-circle" height="40" width="40"/>
        </span>
          <div class="chat-body clearfix">
              <div class="header">
                <strong class="primary-font">User B</strong> <small class="pull-right text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>12 mins ago</small>
              </div>
              <p> 
                Last message sent B
              </p>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>            <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
          <img src="http://www.curlhairstyles.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/short-pixie-hairstyles-for-round-faces-2012.jpg" class="img-circle" height="40" width="40"/>
        </span>
          <div class="chat-body clearfix">
              <div class="header">
                <strong class="primary-font">User C</strong> <small class="pull-right text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>1 mins ago</small>
              </div>
              <p> 
                Last message sent C
              </p>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>            <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
          <img src="http://turnlol.com/images/2012/10/women-models-mena-suvari-american-beauty-faces-white-background-1600x1200-hd-wallpaper.jpg" class="img-circle" height="40" width="40"/>
        </span>
          <div class="chat-body clearfix">
              <div class="header">
                <strong class="primary-font">User D</strong> <small class="pull-right text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>1 hr ago</small>
              </div>
              <p> 
                Last message sent D
              </p>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>           
        <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
          <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-PWtDcqcFWcg/TtdkqM3IsZI/AAAAAAAABu4/AdkNyL8xe-U/s1600/smiling-faces01.jpg" class="img-circle" height="40" width="40"/>
        </span>
          <div class="chat-body clearfix">
              <div class="header">
                <strong class="primary-font">User E</strong> <small class="pull-right text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>19 mins ago</small>
              </div>
              <p> 
                Last message sent E
              </p>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>            <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
          <img src="http://dolchaybanana.blog.com/files/2010/12/ws_Aishwarya_Rai_face_1600x1200.jpg" class="img-circle" height="40" width="40"/>
        </span>
          <div class="chat-body clearfix">
              <div class="header">
                <strong class="primary-font">User F</strong> <small class="pull-right text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>8 mins ago</small>
              </div>
              <p> 
                Last message sent F
              </p>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>            <li class="clearfix"><a href="#"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
          <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-cYickKEX6gE/UL3_l5gzXcI/AAAAAAAA7MM/tsKJ5xyzfkM/s1600/famo+3.jpg" class="img-circle" height="40" width="40"/>
        </span>
          <div class="chat-body clearfix">
              <div class="header">
                <strong class="primary-font">User G</strong> <small class="pull-right text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>29 mins ago</small>
              </div>
              <p> 
                Last message sent G
              </p>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="./Dashboard Template for Bootstrap_files/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Dashboard Template for Bootstrap_files/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Dashboard Template for Bootstrap_files/docs.min.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

Here is the custom CSS I use (note that this is mainly the CSS from the original layout, I've changed little):

```
@import url(css/bootstrap.css);

/*.nav {
padding: 0px 0;
}*/
/*
 * Base structure
 */


/*
 * Global add-ons
 */

.sub-header {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}


/*
 * Sidebar
 */

/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  }
}

/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
  margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Semantically you can't have an <li> inside an <a> - Put the <a> inside the LI and then everything else inside that.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, if I do that then the images disappear. Is there a workaround to have both the responsiveness and the image with img-circle pull-left?

Comment: What do you mean the image disappear when you do that?  Sounds to me like bootstrap is over-complicating your code to me...  I avoid bootstrap like the plague, that's just my personal preference.

Comment: @Michael It seems that the responsive elements 'overlay' the image, despite it being it the same <li>.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the issue. I had a small mistake with regard to my nesting. The others remain, however.

Comment: Can you update your post with the fix to your nesting and remove the issue you fixed please?

Comment: Of course, my apologies. I've made a few aesthetic changes too, but the things I note above remain. I've also included the custom CSS.